# Kotlin generics in Criteria Api

Tags: kotlin, generics, criteria-api

I'm trying to add dynamic predicate translating some domain objects into  `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate`, however I have problems with correctly specifying types in generic methods. Below is a simplified piece of code presenting more or less the method contract I have to uphold. By that I mean that both `path` and `value` are calculated somehow.

```kotlin
enum class Operator { EQUAL, NOT_EQUAL, GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, GREATER_THAN, LESS_THAN, }

inline fun <T> buildPredicate(
            root: Root<*>,
            builder: CriteriaBuilder,
            operator: Operator,
            pathSupplier: () -> Path<T>,
            valueSupplier: () -> T
        ) {
            val path = pathSupplier()
            val value = valueSupplier()
            when (operator) {
                EQUAL -> builder.equal(path, value)              // ok
                GREATER_THAN -> builder.greaterThan(path, value) // this wont compile though
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
            }
        }
```

On the marked line it shows

`None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.`

there is a definition I'm targeting though

`<Y extends Comparable<? super Y>> Predicate greaterThan(Expression<? extends Y> x, Y y);`

**Is this even doable?**

As a side note I may add that in runtime `T` from the example above will resolve to either some `enum`, `String` or `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply the bounds for the method using the `where T: Comparable<T>` clause (see amended method below) - further info - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure;

```
inline fun <T> buildPredicate(
    root: Root<*>,
    builder: CriteriaBuilder,
    operator: Operator,
    pathSupplier: () -> Path<T>,
    valueSupplier: () -> T
) where T: Comparable<T>{
    val path = pathSupplier()
    val value = valueSupplier()
    when (operator) {
        Operator.EQUAL -> builder.equal(path, value)              // ok
        Operator.GREATER_THAN -> builder.greaterThan(path, value) // this compiles
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
}
```